# How to make a popup window with posting data?

Tags: jquery, popup

I would like to make a popup window, but when I popup the window, I would like to post some information, how can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the popup within the form's `.submit` handler and set the form's target to the popup.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
    window.open('', 'popupform', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');

    // target the form to the newly opened popup
    this.target = "popupform";
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/59jtK/)

Answer (score 0):

just

```
window.open("yoururl.php", "_blank", "width=400,height=500");
```

and there, in new window, use

```
$(function(){
    $.post('some_post_script.php', {data:'here'}, function(){
       alert('post sent');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it through your form, you can use the [Form2Pop script by Peter Bailey](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/form2popup.shtml).

Add this javascript to your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/*
Form2Pop Script- By Peter Bailey (http://www.peterbailey.net)
Featured on JavaScriptKit.com
Visit http://www.javascriptkit.com for this script and more
*/

function createTarget(t){
window.open("", t, "width=600,height=550");
return true;
}

</script>
```

And then when you're creating your form

```
<form action="/someurl" onsubmit="return createWebChat(this.target)" target="popupWindow">
```

This will POST your form to /someurl and open up the result in a new window. Then you can adjust the pop up window to your liking by editing the window.open().